# .htaccess don't allow user to view my folder files that don't have index.php

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

On my server, I've created a folder that doesn't have an index.php or index.html.

```
folder1/test.php
folder1/sample.php
folder1/hello.php
```

When I tried to visit that folder, it shows all the files in there.

That is my concern, it should not show the files in my folder because it is prone to hacking. It should display a page like a 403 Forbidden. I don't want to used an index.php just to redirect them to somewhere.

I heard that this involves .htaccess and this is a smart thing to do.

Kindly teach me how to do it.

Comment: And why the "cross-server" (nginx, apache, IIS, whatnot) option of putting e.g. and `index.html` file with `<html><body></body></html>` in the directories you don't want to be served automatically is bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `.htaccess` file in your document root...

```
Options -Indexes
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Comment: Hi there, your answer works like a charm. By the way, I look at the link that you posted. It just shows the explanation of -Indexes, but what does Options with a dash (Options -) means?
Thanks! :)

Comment: It's all there; *The Options directive controls which server features are available in a particular directory.*

Answer (score 2):

That is called directory listing. You have to add a file named `.htaccess` in folder1 and add the following line to it

```
IndexIgnore *
```

to prevent directory listing to list any files.

Comment: If i'll do that, it's like putting an index.php or index.html on all of the directories, but yours is an .htaccess. There could be more folder added in the future, not just the folder1. So I think, it is good to define it in the root .htaccess.
Thanks for you answer anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called 'Directory Browsing' and is a bad thing, usually.  To prevent directory browsing, create or modify a .htaccess file in the root of your site.

If you create an .htaccess file, place this line inside of it:

> ```
> Options All -Indexes
> ```

If modifying, look for

> Options All +Indexes

and change it to `Options All -Indexes`

If you do not see an Indexes directive, add the line from option 1.  That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Or this:

```
IndexIngnore *
```

But for the .htaccess to be honored you have to put something simlar to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

In the httpd.conf or similar in your server configuration