# htaccess - can block directory view, but files are still directly viewable

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hotlinking my Cascading Style Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563721/hotlinking-my-cascading-style-sheets)

This is a bit of a follow up to this question [.htaccess don't allow user to view my folder files that don't have index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845315/htaccess-dont-allow-user-to-view-my-folder-files-that-dont-have-index-php) which worked perfectly for blocking directory level access, but it still doesn't block direct access if someone knew the url

i.e. domain.com/css/ is forbidden, but domain.com/css/main.css shows the css file

how would i block direct access to that file? it seems like such a standard thing but i can't find anything for it

Comment: What about not uploading the file into a public web server directory then? Or do you want *conditional* access, for certain IPs or with a password...?

Comment: Take a look at [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html)

Comment: @deceze Ultimately i'm probably going to take everything that isn't .php file out of my public_html folder and store them outside that directory. But i'd also like to know how to block access to them as well.

Comment: cheers @Teneff i'll have a read through that.

Comment: Honestly what are you trying to achieve with this? Do you expect your page to load that CSS file? Because then it needs to be public.

Comment: no i know the page won't load the css, however i figure the less files a user can load directly, the more secure a site is going to be

Comment: @mrmojorisin But then how do you send the CSS to the browser? In my opinion this won't make your site more secure (maybe even less secure). If you still want to do this, my answer will help. Also, you should take your PHP files out of the `public_html`, not everything else. Leave there the files that will be loaded by the browser, like CSS, JS, images, fonts, etc., unless you want to protect them for some reason (users have to pay to see them, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set restrictions like this:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all #everyone will not be allowed except the following line
Allow from 127.0.0.1 123.123.123.123 #allowed hosts separated by space
```

Comment: i think this is something close to what i'm after. the logic seems better to me, however i'm just getting an internal server error. it's as if it's not recognising localhost

Comment: @mrmojorisin actually I wasn't sure about localhost but you can always replace it with `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

In the `.htaccess` for the directory, you can write:

```
Deny from All
```

This way nobody will be able to access anything in the directory remotely.

Comment: sorry, should have made it clear in the first post, i still need to allow access to the various .php files throughout the directories and the .php files will still call .css and .js files and other .php files

Comment: @mrmojorisin I think you are doing something strange here. Your PHP files will be able to access anything WHEN they are running on the server. If the client views your page, his browser will need to download the CSS, JS, etc. files, so those should remain accessible.

Comment: yes i want them to remain accessible but only when being called by a .php class/file. if a user types in directly to the url domain.com/css/main.css i don't want them to be able to see anything. i know the css itself is harmless, but if someone or myself was to unknowingly drop a file into the web root which might have more sensitive details then i still wouldn't want that file to be able to be directly accessible via the url

Comment: @mrmojorisin Hm, do you understand that you can't make a difference? If the browser can download the CSS, anyone can download the CSS, through a PHP file or not, whatever you try to do.

Comment: ok fair enough. i thought there would be a way to block direct access to a file. it would explain why i couldn't find anything on google.

Comment: @mrmojorisin Do some reading on HTTP. I had the same doubts previously about hiding files, but learning about HTTP, how the client and server communicates helped a lot.

Comment: cheers mate. will have a look.